# How do you create a summary for a blog post?

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column, blog

I want to be able to to add a summary column to my blog posts for ease of visual to another site.  At first I attempted a Calculated column

```
=LEFT([Body], 140)
```

But that doesn't work, I assume because a blog's body is richtext.  Does anyone know how I can create another column for the Post list on a blog that would be a shortened version of the Body column?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right, the **body** field has `rich-text` as a data type that is is not supported in calculated field formulas.

So , if you need to create a new field that will hold summary data from body field , try to Create simple custom workflow via SharePoint designer, and use  `Extract String from start of string`  and `update list item` action as the following :

- In your list add Summary Body field that will hold the summary data 140 character,
- Open SharePoint Designer > click on Workflow > from the above ribbon > select - List Workflow And select your Blog List.
- From the Above Ribbon, > Action > select String from start of string`

[image]

- Set the number of character that you need (140), select body field , and set it at variable.
- Then add `update list item` action to update the summary body field from this variable

**Workflow should look like**

[image]

But if you need to customize Blog home page to show in summery with button read more , in this case, you can truncate HTML content via JSLink by setting `var headlineLimit = 140;`

```
(function () {

    var rCtx = {};
    rCtx.Templates = {};
    rCtx.Templates.Fields = {
        'Body': { 'View' : renderHeadline }
    };
    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(rCtx);
})();


function renderHeadline(ctx) {
    var headlineLimit = 140;
    var body = ctx.CurrentItem.Body;  
    var headline = $(body).text(); 
    if (headline.length > headlineLimit)
    {
        headline = headline.substring(0,headlineLimit) + '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<b><a href="' + ctx.listUrlDir + '/Post.aspx?ID=' + ctx.CurrentItem.ID + '">More ...</a></b>';
    }
    return headline;
}
```

For JSLINK , Check the detail steps at [Sharepoint Online - How to show blogs in excerpt format](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/113892/sharepoint-online-how-to-show-blogs-in-excerpt-format)

Comment: Thanks M! This was great.  The only thing I would add to anyone watching is when setting the start string make sure you tell it plain text so it removes any HTML tags when creating the variable.